# Add an Item Group to Sales Order in Netsuite using SuiteTalk and PHP

Tags: netsuite, itemgroup, suitetalk, php-toolkit

I am trying to add Sales Orders with items of type "Item Group" using SuiteTalk via the PHP Toolkit.

When the item is of other types, e.g. "Inventory Item, Non-Inventory Item", the orders is added without problems.

When the item is of type "Item Group", I get the following error:

> Code: INVALID_KEY_OR_REF 
>   Message: Invalid price reference key 1 for
>   item NNNNNN. Type: ERROR

Where NNNNN is the internal ID of the child Inventory Item connected to this Item Group

Here is how I set my SalesOrderItem:

```
$nsItem = new SalesOrderItem();

$nsItem->item = new RecordRef();
$nsItem->item->internalId = $orderItem->product->foreignId;
$nsItem->item->type = $orderItem->product->itemType;
$nsItem->item->typeSpecified = true;

$nsItem->price = new RecordRef();
$nsItem->price->type = "priceLevel";
$nsItem->price->internalId = "-1"; // the default custom price level
$nsItem->rate = $orderItem->amounts->price;

$nsItem->quantity = $orderItem->qty;
```

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

I made a workaround - I am checking each Sales Order Item for its type and if it is "Item Group" I am populating the Sales Order with the items from this group. It is a little bit slower but works.

Comment: Does it let you save without a price level?

Comment: If the price level is not set I get the same error: Invalid price reference key 1 for item NNNNNN.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this error, you'll notice that the item ID which is causing the error is **not** the same item specified on the header level of the invoice/sales order. The issue here is the "Base Price" (or whatever price level is internal ID `1`) is not defined on that component item of the item group.

If you specify the "Base Price" this error will disappear!

Comment: You are right - dealing with Group Items have to be handled differently as I did.